# Как сделать что-бы после обработки обрезки фото модальное окно закрылось при нажатии на кнопку обрезать

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
function openModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}
function closeModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
function outsideClick(e){
  if(e.target == modal){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

    //обрезалка
var cropper = $('.cropper');

if (cropper.length) {
  $.each(cropper, function(i, val) {
    var uploadCrop;

    var readFile = function(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[i]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
            url: e.target.result
          });
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
      } else {
        alert("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
      }
    };

    uploadCrop = $('.js-cropping').croppie({ // TODO: fix so its selects right element
      viewport: {
        width: 250,
        height: 280
      },
      boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 290
      },
      enableOrientation: true
    });

    $('.js-cropper-upload').on('change', function() {
      $('.crop').show(); // TODO: fix so its selects right element
      readFile(this);
    });
    
    $('.js-cropper-rotate--btn').on('click', function(ev) {
      uploadCrop.croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
    });

    $('.js-cropper-result--btn').on('click', function(ev) {
      uploadCrop.croppie('result', 'canvas').then(function(resp) {
        popupResult({
          src: resp
        });
      });
    });
    var popupResult = function(result) {
      var html;

      if (result.html) {
        html = result.html;
      }

      if (result.src) {
        html = '<img src="' + result.src + '" />';
      }

      $('.js-cropper-result').html(html); // TODO: fix so its selects right element
    };
  });
}
```

```css
.modal{
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.modal-content{
  background-color: #fff;
 margin: 1% auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 81%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
  animation-name:modalopen;
  animation-duration:1s;

}
.closeBtn{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    font-size:46px;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 0 27px 10px auto;
    
}
.cropper-light button{
    background-color: rgb(251, 216, 169);
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 18px;

}
.cropper-light button:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    opacity: .7;
}
@keyframes modalopen{
  from{ opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
.modal-content{
        text-align: center;
        display: block;

}
.cropper {
    padding: 5px 0; // remove
    }

    .cropper__upload {
        width: 100%; // remove
    }

    .cropper__result {
        display: none;
    }
    .js-cropper-upload{
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.5.0/croppie.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.5.0/croppie.min.js"></script>
<div class="cropper-light" id="modalBtn">
                            <button>Вставить портрет</button>
                            </div>
  <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="closeBtn">
        <i>&times;</i>
        </div>
   <div class="cropper"> 
  <input type="file" class="js-cropper-upload" value="Select" name="my_file" accept="image/*,image/jpeg"/> 
  <div class="crop"> 
    <div class="js-cropping"></div> 
    <button class="js-cropper-rotate--btn" data-deg="-90">Повернуть</button>
    <button  id="SaveOneModal" class="js-cropper-result--btn send-file">Обрезать</button>
  </div> 
  <div class="send-file"></div> 
    </div> 
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в конце обработки обрезания одно из:

```
1) $('.modal').attr('style', 'display:none');
2) $('.modal').hide();
```